# Windows Installer: Check installed PowerShell version

Tags: powershell, wix, windows-installer, powershell-4.0

I want to modify an existing MSI package, that it checks if at least PowerShell version 5.0 is installed on the target. If not the installer should abort.

Is there an easy way to detect which version of PowerShell is installed in a WIX project?

Base on this [link](http://0ptikghost.blogspot.co.at/2011/03/executing-powershell-scripts-silently.html) I added the following custom action:

```
 <Property Id="POWERSHELLEXE" Secure="yes">
        <RegistrySearch Id="POWERSHELLEXE"
                        Type="raw"
                        Root="HKLM"
                        Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell"
                        Name="Path" />
    </Property>
    <Condition Message="This application requires Windows PowerShell.">
        <![CDATA[Installed OR POWERSHELLEXE]]>
    </Condition>

    <SetProperty Id="TestPSVersion"
             Before="TestPSVersion"
             Sequence="execute"
             Value ="&quot;[POWERSHELLEXE]&quot; -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command { $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -eq 7 }" />

    <CustomAction Id="TestPSVersion"
          BinaryKey="WixCA"
          DllEntry="CAQuietExec"
          Execute="deferred"
          Return="check"
          Impersonate="yes" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="TestPSVersion" Before="InstallFiles">NOT  Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

I'm actually checking against PS-version 7 to force failure of the custom action. Based on the log is see that the custom action is called during installation process:

```
Action 08:42:09: SetTestPSVersion. 
Action start 08:42:09: SetTestPSVersion.
Action ended 08:42:09: SetTestPSVersion. Return value 1.
Action 08:42:09: TestPSVersion. 
Action start 08:42:09: TestPSVersion.
TestPSVersion: 
Action ended 08:42:09: TestPSVersion. Return value 1.
```

Actually I'm stuck returning the result of PSVersion check. Can anyone help me with that?

Thx

Comment: Not familiar with WiX specifically, but usually I use the "search" feature to locate files in the file system or registry and set a property, which you can use in a launch condition.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Looking at what you have I would think that the CA needs to be immediate rather then deferred.